# Principal value of an integral

Tags: integration, cauchy-principal-value

Let's consider the following integral:

$$I(y)=\text{PV} \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x) dx}{x^2-y^2}$$

Where PV is the Cauchy principal value, $y \in \mathbb{R}, \qquad y>0$.

It can be shown by definition that:

$$\text{PV} \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2-y^2}=0$$

> Then would it be correct to state:

$$I(y)=\int_0^\infty \frac{(f(x)-f(y)) dx}{x^2-y^2}$$

Where we now have a convergent integral.

> What conditions should $f(x)$ satisfy for this to work? Can it be discontinuous?

---

The reason I'm asking is because there's a case with $f(x)=\theta(x-z)$, there $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function and $y<z$, which makes the original integral convergent.

Then applying the method I suggested leads to a different value for the integral, than the one I get by taking it directly.

Comment: "It can be shown by definition that...". What if $y=0$? Then it looks like you do not have a value even in the PV sense? Can you check that what you write is what you mean, or clarify?

Comment: @mickep, thank you, I added the condition that $y>0$, because it's the case I'm interested in

Comment: If $y<z$, then $f(y)=\theta(y-z)=0$. Using your method you get $$ I(y) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\theta(x-z)\,dx}{x^2-y^2} = \int_z^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2-y^2}$$ which is equal to the principal value, as it has no singularities in the integration interval. I can't see how you can obtain a different result calculating the same integral.

Comment: If the integral $I$ of $f + g$ exists, then the p.v. integral of $f + g$ exists and equals $I$, and if the p.v. integral $I_g$ of $g$ exists, the p.v. integral of $f = (f + g) - g$ has to exist and be equal to $I - I_g$.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński, you are right, I made a mistake and forgot that $\theta(y-z)=0$ if $y<z$, which does make both cases the same. Thank you